Как определить какой браузер запущен и какие вкладки открыты?
Хочу сделать код, который будет запущен и при открытии часто используемых браузеров (яндекс, хром, эйдж), оповестит об этом. Также хотелось бы знать какие вкладки открываются и закрываются. Можно ли такое сделать и в какую сторону стоит копать?

"любого" - это сразу же невозможно

@andreymal хорошо, из существующих и часто используемых. Хром, Яндекс, Эйдж

Список процессов можно получить, а оттуда выловить список запущенных браузеров. Но это НЕ решение вопроса. Потому что это всё менялось и будет меняться. Такая программа - из серии лишь бы живо, "на мой век хватит", из серии "большой красной кнопки - любимой игрушки Большого Брата". Энергия, которая будет потрачена на эту бесполезность и временность, несравнима с выгодой. Не всё программируют, хотя многое хотят.

@FoxFox хорошо, тогда какой еще есть вариант решения задачи?

Если пройтись по всем процессам, можно получииь путь до exe файла и через фильтр определить какие браузеры запущены. Каждая вкладка это отдельный процесс, можно из заголовка дёрнуть описание вкладки. И соответственно в цикле крутить и отслеживать изменения.

Вы можете использовать ctypes или pyautogui, которая использует ctypes. Второй вариант проще, так же он может манипулировать окнами. Так же можно использовать win32gui
пример pyautogui:
import pyautogui

for i in pyautogui.getAllWindows():
  print(i.title)

пример win32gui:
import win32gui


def enum_callback(hwnd, a):
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if "chrome" in title.lower():
        print(title.lower())


win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_callback, 0)

дополнение к pyautogui:
если вам важно что бы библиотека занимала меньше памяти, тогда pyautogui можно сократить только до нужных функций, т.к. там много лишнего. для этого смотрите файл _pygetwindow_win

В первом примере код показывает, что запущен яндекс браузер, хотя он выключен. Это ошибка библиотеки или он реагирует даже на просто установленные браузеры

@dynamic.aerospace.inc, возможно влияние фонового процесса либо свернутого в трей

@dynamic.aerospace.inc нет, на просто установленные реагировать не должен. Возможно он запущен где-то в фоне. Иногда это можно определить по различным данным этого окна. Например координаты около -32000 (точно не помню) означали, что окно свёрнуто
